# Change gradient in ApplyStyleLookup

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

Im trying to change the gradient color of TSpeedbutton at runtime using ApplyStyleLookup, but for some reason only the top twothird of the button changes color. When I change it at design time I see three points for the gradient. I'm using the buttonstyle in the TSpeedbuttons StyleLookup. Using Delphi XE6 Rad Studio.

Thanks.
Added 8/29/14 I found the way to change the gradient see below. But my problem is on the buttonstyle have three rectangles and the one I need to access is the rectangle2 under background. What do I need to access it.

```
procedure TForm1.SpeedButton1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  BckObject: TFmxObject;
begin
  BckObject := SpeedButton1.FindStyleResource('background');
  if Assigned(BckObject) and (BckObject is TRectAngle) then
  begin
    TRectAngle(BckObject).Fill.Gradient.Style := TGradientStyle.Linear;
    TRectAngle(BckObject).Fill.Gradient.Points.Points[0].Color := $FF0097A5;
    TRectAngle(BckObject).Fill.Gradient.Points.Points[0].Offset := 0.25;
    TRectAngle(BckObject).Fill.Gradient.Points.Points[1].Color := $FF0097F5;
    TRectAngle(BckObject).Fill.Gradient.Points.Points[1].Offset := 1.00;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: This will vary from style to style, before anyone can even attempt to answer you have to provide which style you are using. Also, why would you use a `TSpeedButton` and then set the styleLookup to buttonstyle, just use a `TButton` then.

Comment: In Stylelookup I selected buttonstyle so i'm not sure what other style you are referring to. I have used Delphi since version 2 and this is my first attempt to make an Android application with Delphi I been using Eclipse for Android apps the last four years. I use TSpeedbutton because I don't want the button to get focus when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle2 (TRectAngle) under background has the StyleName property blank, by enter a name in the StyleName and save it I can access the rectangle2 by using the same method:
BckObject := SpeedButton1.FindStyleResource('myname');